# Where is the Screen Node?

Tags: node-editor

In this amazing [Blog](http://blenderthings.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/a-fabric-osl-shader-for-blender-cycles.html) I found a OSL Shader for fabric, but now I'm stuck because I can't find the Node called *Screen*. I tried the search menu <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Search...*

[image]

Comment: I know this is ancient but I was curios about the shader - current url is https://blog.michelanders.nl/2012/12/a-fabric-osl-shader-for-blender-cycles_55.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a *[MixRGB node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html#mix-node)* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *Add node menu > Color > MixRGB*) which is set to [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen):

[image]